# Most efficient way to model data in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an example of modelling an commence site. Say that the site has few hundreds shops and few millions products. The products per shop range: 1000-100.000 products/shop. I need to be able to aggregate the products and the shop fields. All the products and all the shops have the same schema.

Product

```
        {
          "productName"
          "price"
          "category"
        }
```

Shop

```
{
  "shopName"
  "rating"
}
```

1)  Is it more efficient to have a) 1 index/shop, b) same index and 1 type/shop or c) same index, same type and have a field to determine the shop of the product?

I read some related articles and most of them are in favour of same index and 1 type/shop. But then they say that if there is one single index which has a large number of docs it might be even slower than having multiple indices.

2) I also need to perform JOINS and aggregations between the shops and the products. For example I need to be able to retrieve all the products from the shops with rating higher than 8/10 and also get the number of products per category. Is it preferable to use a) application-side JOIN, b) parent-child relationships, c) [Siren plug-in](https://siren.solutions/relational-joins-for-elasticsearch-the-siren-join-plugin/), d) something else?

Comment: I had to solve similar problem lately. First of all sit down and write down your all search scenarios – think how data will be searched and what you need to return from your query. Then read about pros and cons of each solution and you will have an answer. For example I wouldn’t use application join if I have thousands of shops with rating higher than 8/10 because you need to provide these thousands IDs to other query and this will make performance issues.

Comment: Thnx Adam. You re right in that I have to think of all the scenarios. Thing is that there are many different ways in which I can structure the data and I don't all the implications. I guess I also need to invest time in understanding how ES internally works

Comment: Have you made any progress?

Comment: Hi Adam , I replied below

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely use single denormalized index/type for the use cases you've mentioned. If you will need more fields for the shop, then you will create another index for shops, while still keeping first denormalized index. Mind that you may need unique shop id alongside to shop name.

Comment: The only problem with denormalized index/type is that your shop data are inside product type and if shop detail will be changed then you need to change all products - off course if there will be such requirements.

Comment: ES index should be perceived as a searchable view of the real data, that's why you should always design index for future reindexing

Comment: Hi guys, I m still looking around. Regarding performance, I did some simple tests and the conclusion was that for ~ 30 shops and ~300.000 products there was no significant difference between 1 index/shop or single index and 1 type/shops. So I am in favour of single index and 1 type/shop cause I also need to use some other indices for metadata, etc. But then , I need to be able to  delete all docs for a specific type(shop) and the thing is that ES 2.x.x does not support it out of the box.

Comment: Regarding the JOIN, I also thought of denormalising my data, but again thing is that I ll have way more fields for "shops" than just "rating" and demoralising all these fields may create lot of data redundancy. So I ll either try parent/child relationship or I may also consider keeping the shops in a cache (Memcache, Hazelcast, etc..), rather than ES. It should be feasible for few hundreds shops... what do you think?